# handler cannot handle objects of this class -10010

Tags: applescript

I was trying to use a script to open CS:GO with an AppleScript program, but I get the error message:

> Handler cannot handle objects of this class -10010

Here's the script:

```
set myfilepath to "Macintosh HD:Users:Kasper:Desktop:Counter-Strike Global Offensive"
tell application "Finder" to open myfilepath
delay 5
tell application "System Events" to set unixID to unix id of process "csgo_osx"
do shell script ("renice -20 -p " & unixID) password "2306" with administrator privileges
```

Any ideas why this happens?

Comment: Please post code, no pictures. What kind of type is CS:GO?

Answer (score 0):

Your second line is telling Finder's Open command to open a string. It needs to be given a file or alias. Change that line to:

```
tell application "Finder" to open file myfilepath
```